# why add_menu_page use simple function as arg while add_meta_box a call back?

Tags: metabox, add-menu-page

I was looking on Wordpress function reference and find that add_menu_page takes simple function as arg while add_meta_box call it as call back. I am new to programming.. help me understand this

Answer (score 4):

The parameters have the same meaning, they are just *named* inconsistent. Both accept calls to a function. This can even be the same function.

Here is a simple demo as a plugin. [Download](https://gist.github.com/1115365)

```
/*
Plugin Name: Callback Demo
Description: Demonstrating how a meta box and a menu page can take the same callback function.
Version:     1.0
Required:    3.1
Author:      Thomas Scholz
Author URI:  http://toscho.de
License:     GPL
Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/24481/
*/
! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) and exit;

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse_24481_demo' );

/**
* Adds a menu page and a meta box with the same callback function.
*
* @return void
*/
function wpse_24481_demo()
{
    $title    = 'Callback Demo';
    $callback = 'wpse_24481_callback';

    add_menu_page( $title, $title, 'edit_posts', 'callback-demo', $callback );
    add_meta_box( 'callback-demo', $title, $callback, 'post' );
}

/**
* Prints the content.
*
* @return void
*/
function wpse_24481_callback()
{
    print 'Here may be dragons.';
}
```

.

### Result

[image]

*page menu*

---

[image]

*meta box*

Comment: Tried to fix the end of that code block 3 times now, no idea what the issue is, doesn't seem to want to format it correctly, whilst preview shows it all in the code block, SE/SO bug of some kind i guess..

Comment: I added a Magic Dot. #fixed :)